# React MaterialUI hosted in ASP.NET Razor Page

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, material-ui, razor-pages

I am developing a application that initially was built using ASP.NET Razor Pages, so I have some .cshtml files.

Recently, new UI I implemented using React and Material UI.

While running React application in separation, it all works nice and looks good:
[image]

Now, in order to display this React page, I need to do this by using built JS bundle and importing it in cshtml with `script` element. This also works, but it displays the search input incorrectly (as shown below). I have also other styles in ASP.NET defined in less that may interfere with MaterialUI styles.

[image]

Any work around such issue?

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, when you observe the elements in question, are there custom style rules overriding any of the MUI framework style rules?

Comment: @David MUI styles are in place, but they're applied directly on input component. But I also have styles that have CSS for selectors like `input[type="text"]` which is also applicable to component in question.

Comment: Well, if you’re overriding the styles then you’re overriding the styles.  It sounds like you may need to take a different approach to your custom styles so they don’t interfere with framework styles that you want to preserve.  That could involve changing your selectors, or even entirely changing how you manage your custom styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I found such solution:

find common (base) CSS classes in MUI framework, when page is rendered, go to dev tools, to HTML sources and there should be some base class for every MUI component, like `MuiInputBase-input`.

This can be used to alter conflicting `less` styles. In order to do so, find file that contains conflicting style (also can be done in dev tools in Sources tab).

For example in my case it was change from:

```
input[type="text"]
```

to

```
input[type="text"]:not(.MuiInputBase-input)
```

Similarly, `button` was also affected, to fix that change styles selector from `button` to

```
button:not(.MuiButtonBase-root)
```